# Long frame paint times but idle CPU and GPU in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

This is a rather broad question of a strange performance issue where a frame takes 1200 ms to paint, but devtools profiling shows that the browser is almost idle (at least no busier than in normal conditions).

Web app that is affected by this issue has a primary purpose of showing a video stream along with some added overlays. To add overlays correctly (e.g. highlight moving objects) they should be in sync with the main video stream. For this purpose the stream includes an additional 32-px strip (which is hidden from the human eye by CSS) with color rectangles encoding a timestamp of the current frame. JavaScript then reads that strip (by drawing a video into the canvas and then retrieving the image data from that canvas), decodes a frame number, fetches required metadata and then paints everthing on the canvas. This process repeats run in animation frame callback. So, the main loop, when expressed in pseudocode, looks like this:

```js
function readFrameNumber() {
  fnCanvas.drawImage(video, sx, sy, sw, sh, 0, 0, 8, 1);
  const data = fnCanvas.getImageData(0, 0, 8, 1).data;
  return ... // decode pixels in data
}

function animationFrameCb() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animationFrameCb);

  if (video.time != lastTime) {
    const frameNumber = readFrameNumber();
    lastTime = video.time;
    
    const metadata = metadataMap.get(frameNumber);
    canvas.clear();
    for (const obj of metadata.objects) drawObject(obj);
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(animationFrameCb);
```

Now, the performance issue itself. If you look at the profiler, you will sometimes see frames like that (along with corresponding UI freezes):

[image: frame]

And I'm really confused what is the cause of such freezes:

- it's not CPU: there is a lot of idle time in JavaScript thread
- it's not GPU either: it's also rather idle
- it's not GC: heap chart shows that no garbage collection takes place during the freeze, and there are no abrupt drops in memory usage chart.
- and what is more interesting - it has multiple animation frame callbacks *inside of a single frozen frame*! All those small yellow ticks on the screenshot are actually invocations of animation frame callback.

Something very weird is happening inside of Chrome itself, and I don't don't know where to look for the further insights. This effect is reproducible at least on Linux desktops, and to a lesser extent on Android phones (it has shorter freeze times, but still noticeable).

Comment: Since you're using `requestAnimationFrame`, you're limited by your frame rate (usually 60 but depends on your monitor). If the work you do in `requestAnimationFrame` takes less time that it takes to get to a new frame (~16ms for 60fps), the rest of the time will be idle. You do have some odd fluctuation there. Slow rate at the beginning and two dense spots in the last half of the section you marked.

Comment: Yes, but all marked section represents a single frame. UI just literally freezes for 1.2 second, no frames are ocurring in between. So I'm wondering why all those calls to `requestAnimationFrame` even occur - there are literally no frames to animate. Also it's a question why their rate doubles shortly after start of the long frozen frame.

Comment: That's a single frame? Because it looks like multiple frames and your code is set up to repeatedly call `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: I see you say just that in your question. Are you able to share a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: What's `canvas.clear()` really? That isn't part of the canvas API.

Comment: It's clearRect with full canvas dimensions. Reproducible example is hard, it doen't even reproduce on some machines while reproducing on others.

Comment: So the intermediate conclusion is that it looks like a rare Chromium bug: it does not reproduce on Windows and it also does not reproduce on Linux with faster GPU.

Comment: It may have to do with difficulty pulling the frame buffer out of the GPU. I know older GPU used to have that problem and mobile GPU still do. (They're optimized for writes over reads as the most common use case by far.)

Comment: Not sure about your profiling results, but anyway given your project you may try to start your context with the `willReadFrequently: true` option, or even better use a secondary canvas with this option only to get the metadata, and use a "normal" one only to draw on it.